# Remover Borda do Report Viewer

Tags: c#, mvc, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

já tentei de várias formas remover esta borda que aparece no report viewer, e não consegui de jeito nenhum.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo está parte do meu código com as propriedades que adicionei para remover a borda:

```
viewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
viewer.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
viewer.Height = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
viewer.BorderWidth = 0;
viewer.InternalBorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.None;
```

O código HTML esta abaixo:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="blockGT">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="icon-chevron-left hide-sidebar"><a href='#' title="Hide Sidebar" rel='tooltip'>&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li class="icon-chevron-right show-sidebar" style="display:none;"><a href='#' title="Show Sidebar" rel='tooltip'>&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li>RELATÓRIO&nbsp;<span class="divider">/</span></li>
                    <li>PAGAMENTOS POR EMPRESA<span class="divider"></span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">
            <div class="muted pull-left"><b>RELATÓRIO DE PAGAMENTOS POR EMPRESA</b></div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content collapse in teste">
            <div class="span12">
                @Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, htmlAttributes: new { @Width = "100%", @Height = "100%" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Essa bordar não é do reportViewer, poderia colocar esse trecho de código html que envolve o componente? A borda do componente já não aparece e outra borda de outro tag!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei o problema e incluí o trecho do código html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É criado um [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), então, adicione essa configuração no `htmlAttributes`: `@style = "border:0"` para remover a bordar.

```
@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, 
          htmlAttributes: new { @Width = "100%", @Height = "100%", @style = "border:0" })
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Valeu